# What's the efficient way to compute the date difference since last maintenance?

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a sample dataset I am working with:

```
            maint id
datetime            
2015-01-01    1.0  a
2015-01-02    NaN  a
2015-01-03    NaN  a
2015-01-04    1.0  a
2015-01-05    NaN  a
2015-01-06    NaN  a
2015-01-07    NaN  a
2015-01-01    NaN  b
2015-01-02    NaN  b
2015-01-03    1.0  b
2015-01-04    1.0  b
2015-01-05    NaN  b
2015-01-06    NaN  b
2015-01-07    NaN  b
```

What I want to get is day difference since `df['maint']` is 1.

```
            maint id  days
datetime                  
2015-01-01    1.0  a     0
2015-01-02    NaN  a     1
2015-01-03    NaN  a     2
2015-01-04    1.0  a     0
2015-01-05    NaN  a     1
2015-01-06    NaN  a     2
2015-01-07    NaN  a     3
2015-01-01    NaN  b     0
2015-01-02    NaN  b     0
2015-01-03    1.0  b     0
2015-01-04    1.0  b     0
2015-01-05    NaN  b     1
2015-01-06    NaN  b     2
2015-01-07    NaN  b     3
```

Because I have thousands different ID, and each ID has maintenance record in couple of years. I would like to find a efficient way in computing day difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['days'] = df.index.where(df['maint'].eq(1))
df['days'] = (df.index - df.groupby('id')['days'].ffill()).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)).dt.days
print (df)
            maint id  days
datetime                  
2015-01-01    1.0  a     0
2015-01-02    NaN  a     1
2015-01-03    NaN  a     2
2015-01-04    1.0  a     0
2015-01-05    NaN  a     1
2015-01-06    NaN  a     2
2015-01-07    NaN  a     3
2015-01-01    NaN  b     0
2015-01-02    NaN  b     0
2015-01-03    1.0  b     0
2015-01-04    1.0  b     0
2015-01-05    NaN  b     1
2015-01-06    NaN  b     2
2015-01-07    NaN  b     3
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create new column `days` with values of `df.index` where `maint` is `1`, another values are `NaT`
2. Subtract `index` by new Series created by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html), replace `NaN`s to `0 timedelta` and last convert them to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html)